# Rails 5: Adding extra characters on the links

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I created a scrolling navigation in rails that requires to visit the `root url + '#about'` and similar section of the page.

Here's my html:

```
<%= link_to "Home", root_path, class: "nav-link", :"data-id" => "home" %>
<%= link_to "About", root_path, class: "nav-link", :"data-id" => "about" %>
<%= link_to "Testimonials", root_path, class: "nav-link", :"data-id" => "testimonials" %>
```

And here's the js code:

```
 // Scrolling Nav
  $(".nav-link").click(function(){
      var topData = $( '#' + $(this).attr("data-id")).offset();
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: topData.top
      }, 'slow');
     });
```

This is by default will scroll to the section with the data-id or div content section id of `home`, `about`, `testimonials`

Is there a way in rails that I can plugin the `root_path` + specific text like `#about` on my link to so if the user clicks the link like `About` link it will parse the url `http://localhost:3000#about`

I tried this:

```
<%= link_to "About", root_path#{#about}, class: "nav-link", :"data-id" => "about" %>
```

But did not work. Is there a way to do this? Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not confident I understood correctly, but you should be able to anchor to desired text like-so:

```
root_path(:anchor => 'about')
```